# Filling in ListLinePlot with self intersection problem and turn-round track/multi-valued line

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

Suppose I have a data list

```
datx = Flatten[#, 1] &@{{#, Sin[#]} & /@ 
Range[-5, 0], {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 1.2}, {1.5, 0.5}, {3.5,
  0.5}}, {#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[4, 7]}
```

which looks like

```
ListLinePlot[{datx}, PlotStyle -> {Black}]
```

[image]

you see that `datx` **runs backward** at around x=2. Note that this short `datx` is only an example. The real data list I analyze and plot might **longer** than 1000.

suppose I have the error bar of the `datx`

```
err = 0.1*Range@Length@datx
```

then I want to plot the uncertainty of datx by

```
ListLinePlot[{datx, datx + ({0, #} & /@ err), 
 datx - ({0, #} & /@ err)}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Gray, Gray}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {3}, Gray}]
```

this looks like

[image: blank area caused by datx running back]

of course this will not satisfies me. What I want is something like this:

[image]

**The red area should be filled** If it represents the uncertainty of the data!
(and strangely that the `Gray` in `PlotStyle` and `Filling` is not the same color..)

What should I do? I'd like work with ListLinePlot which is convient but a general solution with many `Graphics` objects will also be accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desired plot can be obtained as follows.  Starting with the `datax` and `err` as defined in the question, compute the points defining the error boundaries.

```
upper = datx + ({0, #} & /@ err);
lower = datx - ({0, #} & /@ err);
```

Then, construct quadrilaterals from all pairs of adjacent points in `upper` and corresponding points in `lower`, and plot them.

```
shading = Graphics[Join[{LightGray}, Polygon /@ Transpose@
    {Most@upper, Rest@upper, Rest@lower, Most@lower}], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

(There are many ways to construct the polygons, but this way is particularly straightforward.)

[image]

Also, plot the three curves as in the question, but without `Filling`.

```
curves = ListLinePlot[{datx, datx + ({0, #} & /@ err), 
    datx - ({0, #} & /@ err)}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Gray, Gray}];
```

Finally, combine the two.

```
Show[shading, curves]
```

[image]

The specified spaces now are filled in.  If the `Gray` error curves are not desired, simply omit them when creating `curves`.

**Addendum**

For completeness, the overlapping quadrilaterals can be visualized by

```
Graphics[Join[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0]}, Polygon /@ Transpose@
    {Most@upper, Rest@upper, Rest@lower, Most@lower}], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Its 3D appearance is an unintended illusion, which disappears when the boundary lines are removed.